# sharing common data on sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

I have a large list of projects with project dates both projected and actual.  I want to share all the dates and all the projects with our internal team, but want to limit the access of our external contractors to just those projects their company is assigned to complete.  I tried managing the content with folders and permissions, but discovered that because my company does not have access 2007, that function is not completely enabled. Does anyone out there have any idea how I can do this?

Thanks

Comment: Is this SharePoint or Project Server?  That are not the same thing even though Project Server does depend on SharePoint.

Comment: You don't mean Access 2007, you mean MOSS 2007, or "Microsoft Office SharePoint Server" 2007.

Comment: Also, you can't have folders in a list so you must mean a document library. If it is a document library, setting the permissions on a folder should work correctly in either WSS or MOSS.

Answer (score 0):

Few facts

- Setting permissions and folders do not have anything with Access 2007.
- You cannot use folders on custom lists only with Document Libraries and Form libraries

In your scenario the best option is to have custom, item level permissions for each project:

1. to do it manually check [this](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointserver/HA100215641033.aspx#10)
2. to do it automatically you should create a workflow with SharePoint Designer. Here is an activity [to do that](http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Grant%20Permission%20on%20Item).

In case you have just a few projects do it manually otherwise configure a workflow to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a dataview webpart to any sites the external companies *can* access. Each webpart can be configured to filter on the information they are responsible for by the metadata field.